# w3wp.exe Command Options

Tags: windows, process, iis

I'm trying to figure out what the '-ap' flag to w3wp.exe (the IIS worker process) is. Running the process with '/?' lists some command flags, but there is no mention of an '-a' or a '-p', not to mention '-ap'. Any ideas?

An example command line:

windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap MSExchangeServicesAppPool -v v2.0 -l webengine4.dll -a \.\pipe\iisipm4cec1b63-67c1-4d7c-b9da-5faf1c5f46e9 -h C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\MSExchangeServicesAppPool\MSExchangeServicesAppPool.config -w  -m 0

Comment: Judging by the fact it names an Application Pool after the switch, I'd say it stands for "Application Pool".

Answer (score 3):

Just by looking at that command I'd say the -ap parameter allows you to specify an application pool. See? It takes a parameter, in this line you are passing `MSExchangeServicesAppPool` as the parameter to that option.